# corruption loop for a data frame in PySpark

Tags: pyspark, corruption

I'm making a loop for corrupt my dataset on PySpark, and i want to control the errors.
First: I made a list of type: 9 errors and 1 with no error.

```py
#code_erreur= [ "replace","inverse","inserte","delete","espace","NA"]
code_erreur= ["replace"]
varibale =["VARIABLEA","VARIABLEB"]
```

I start with just code the error : replace. 
Select a random letter, on a random "varibale ", to replace by antoher random letter .

My input:
VARIABLEA  | VARIABLEB
BLUE            |  WHITE
PINK             | DARK

My expected output:
VARIABLEA  | VARIABLEB
BLTE            |  WHITE
PINK             | DARM

And I made a loop:

```py
def algo_corruption(lettre,code_erreur,nombre_erreur,varibale,data): 
  alp=(list(string.ascii_uppercase))  
  table_corruption=[]
  for i in range(1,data.count()):
    
    code_erreur_choisi =random.choice(code_erreur)
    varibale_choisie =random.choice(varibale)
  
    (table_corruption.append((code_erreur_choisi,
                            varibale_choisie)))
    
  cols=["code_erreur_choisi","varibale_choisie"]
  result = spark.createDataFrame(table_corruption, cols)
  result= result.withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id())
  data= data.withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id())
  data_join_result= data.join(result, "id","inner").drop("id")

  for j in range(1,data_join_result.count()):
    if data_join_result.filter(col("code_erreur_choisi") == "replace"):
      data_corrp = (data_join_result[varibale_choisie].replace(random.choice(data_join_result.collect()[j][varibale_choisie]),
                                                               random.choice(alp))
      display(data_corrp)
    
    else:
      print("erreur pas encore codée")
```

But that doesn't work, I always have errors like:

```
ValueError: R
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-3614001298541202> in <module>()
----> 1 algo_corruption(code_erreur,varibale,extrac_base_train)

<command-1181487391956055> in algo_corruption(code_erreur, varibale, data)
     29     if data_join_result.filter(col("code_erreur_choisi") == "replace"):
     30       data_corrp = (data_join_result[varibale_choisie].replace(random.choice(data_join_result.collect()[j][varibale_choisie]),
---> 31                                                                data_join_result.collect()[j][lettre_choisie]))
     32       display(data_corrp)
     33 

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/types.py in __getitem__(self, item)
   1517             raise KeyError(item)
   1518         except ValueError:
-> 1519             raise ValueError(item)
   1520 
   1521     def __getattr__(self, item):

ValueError: R
```

Comment: Please include the full stacktrace of your error message.

Comment: Added in the question.

Comment: Its not a good idea to loop through a dataframe using collect. Can you try processing this in a udf as shown here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62817795/error-message-in-a-loop-for-on-pypsark-using-regexp-replace ? If you still want to proceed like this, can you post a sample of how the data_join looks like? because i am sure even this line of code will not work - ````if data_join_result.filter(col("code_erreur_choisi") == "replace"):````. To make advantage of spark features, consider revamping your code